# K4W with openni

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, libfreenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been looking into using Kinect for Windows on Ubuntu. However, it seems not to be possible with openni at the moment. I found an interesting post regarding libfreenect, where they apparently did get it to work: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/274 and  https://github.com/renewagner/libfreenect/tree/k4w-wip

As ROS seems to be doing more in terms of development regarding the openni stack as opposed to the libfreenect driver. I was wondering if someone else has been working on getting these features into the openni driver. I did find a bridge between the windows sdk and openni: https://www.assembla.com/code/kinect-mssdk-openni-bridge/git/nodes/for-kinect-sdk-v10/release/kinect-mssdk-openni-bridge-1.0-1.5.2.23.zip .We are limited to the linux platform however, so this is not a possibility. Does anyone have more information regarding the subject?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31276/k4w-with-openni/) by [Timdejager](https://answers.ros.org/users/2021/timdejager/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are some more informations about "Kinect for Windows (K4W)".
http://answers.ros.org/question/12876/kinect-for-windows?answer

Actually it seems to be that the openni has no upgrade for the K4W.
I cant give you more informations.

---

Originally posted by [GermanUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2107/germanuser/) with karma: 125 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0